# Scale an image saved on android device

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am adding a frame to a picture taken with the devices camera.
When saving the image it looks too zoomed in as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UREN.jpg

I am trying to scale  image using this code:

```
private fun getScaledBitMapBaseOnScreenSize(bitmapOriginal: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    var scaledBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    try {
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
        val width = bitmapOriginal.width
        val height = bitmapOriginal.height
        val scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity
        val scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity

        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        val matrix = Matrix()
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
        
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    Log.d(TAG, scaledBitmap.toString())
    return scaledBitmap
}
```

The getScaledBitmap returns null, looking inside inside the method Bitmap.createBitmap returns null. More odd is the device size and scale is the same as the image taken so this method is practically useless.

I want to get the frame and the captured image in the right scale. I am not sure if I should resize or maybe change the way I build the joint image as seen below

```
cameraKitView.captureImage { cameraKitView, capturedImage ->
            val date = Date()
            val imgName = "Casino Fun $date"

            var capturedImage : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                capturedImage, 0, capturedImage.size
            )
                .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            var canvas = Canvas(capturedImage)
            val curFrame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, activeFrameSource)
            val paint = Paint()

            canvas.drawBitmap(curFrame, 0f, 0f, paint)
            try {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    contentResolver,
                    getScaledBitMapBaseOnScreenSize(capturedImage),
                    imgName,
                    "Image Saved"
                )
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the curFrame bitmap, it's size was way bigger to match the takenImage size, so I have to resize it using

```
val scaledFrame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(curFrame, takenImage.width, takenImage.height, false)
```

Another thing I would advise is verifying the designs you are getting.